# Automatic zoom/set width on Flutter webview

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I'm using the webview plugin to show a graph in my app. The sample code works fine and it displays the website with the graph I want to show. I want it to be automatically zoomed in for me to be able to read it better, and also because I'm adding multiple graphs in one page. The website only has one component (the graph) and nothing else (no headers or anything else) so I figured I can't use javascript methods where I can program my app not to show specific parts of the webpage.

Here is my current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFCFCFC),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('test',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 28.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            letterSpacing: 2.5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            /*Container(
              height: 90,
              width: 90,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),*/
            Container(
              height: 150,
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://thingspeak.com/channels/1864145/charts/1?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=60&title=Carbon+Dioxide+Concentrations&type=line',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was wondering if there's a method where I can automatically zoom the website. If not, are there other plugins that support this?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use height and width parameters proposed by thinkspeaks
to give the chart the container size by using auto value: height=auto and width=auto.

You should have the following link

https://thingspeak.com/channels/1864145/charts/1?bgcolor=%23ffffff&height=auto&width=auto&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=60&title=Carbon+Dioxide+Concentrations&type=line

Here is the link for more: https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/createchart.html

You can also get all data from thinkspeaks and plot that using flutter plotting package (fl_chart for example).
https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/readfield.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34664534)

Comment: the link is just for the illustration purpose, based on the link he put in the question.